# Can ransomware detect Virtual Environments?

Tags: virtualization, ransomware, vmware

My title says it all but here is a scenario:
I download a suspicions file and run it inside a VM.If everything works, I will deploy it to my original PC.

I plan to use these:
1.Oracle VM
2.Vmware
3.Hybrid Analysis

So, can a ransomware detect these at the first place?

Comment: Yes, some ransomware can detect some virtual environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, malware can detect being run under a virtual machine ("sandbox") environment.  There are a number of techniques:

- Checking how long ago the system booted
- Checking the registry for entries associated with VM software
- Checking the location in memory of common structures
- Checking for files, processes, or services associated with VM software
- Checking hardware-specific details like MAC addresses
- Checking CPU instructions like MMX that aren't usually found in VMs

Far more detail is available online; I'd suggest googling *malware virtual machine detection* to begin.

Comment: I was planning to use Hybrid Analysis, can most of the ransomware detect it?

Comment: When you say Hybrid Analysis do you mean the product at "hybrid-analysis.com"? If so, you might want to contact their customer support to get an answer to this question.

Comment: @hft  Yes, I mean hybrid-analysis.com.I will contact them.